# Can someone help me simplify this boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, mathematical-physics, computer-algebra-systems, computer-arithmetic

ABCD + AB(CD)' + (AB)'CD
when i used basic rule it becomes weird
but boolean calculator shows something else

The Question is to simplify the expression using the boolean algebra 
so My solution was 
ABCD + AB(CD)' + (AB)'CD
=AB(CD + (C'+D') + (AB)'CD
=AB(1) + (A'+B')CD 
=AB + A'CD + B'CD
now from here i'm little confused

solution according to calculator is :
(A+C)(A+D)(B+C)(B+D)

Comment: Please show us what you've done, so far.  The first two products simplify to $(AB(CD + (CD)') =  AB$.  It is inappropriate on this site to post an exercise, and not provide any context along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition initial shows that:

\begin{align}
ABCD + AB(CD)' &+ (AB)'CD  \\
\left(ABCD + AB(CD)'\right) &+ (AB)'CD  \\
AB\left(CD + (CD)'\right) &+ (AB)'CD  \\
AB &+ (AB)'CD  \\
\left( (AB)'\right. &\left. \    \  \left( \left(AB \right)'CD \right)' \right)' \\
\left( (AB)' \right.  & \  \ \left.\left( AB+\left(CD\right)' \right) \right)' \\
\left( (AB)'AB\right. &+\left.(AB)'\left(CD\right)' \right)' \\
\left((AB)'\right. & \ \ \  \ \left.\left(CD\right)' \right)' \\
AB &+ CD \\
\end{align}

But the solution according to the calculator leads to:

\begin{equation}
(A+C)(A+D)(B+C)(B+D)  \\
(A+AD+AC+CD)(B+BD+BC+CD)  \\
\end{equation}

But there is an axiom that $A+AB = A(A+B) = A$, then:

\begin{equation}
(A+AD+AC+CD)(B+BD+BC+CD)  \\
(A+AC+CD)(B+BC+CD)  \\
(A+CD)(B+CD)  \\
AB+CD  \\
\end{equation}

Then these two answers are the same.

Answer (score 2):

$$ABCD+AB(CD)'+(AB)'CD=AB(CD+(CD)')+(AB)'CD=$$
$$=AB+(AB)'CD=\left((AB)'\left(AB+(CD)'\right)\right)'=\left((AB)'(CD)'\right)'=AB+CD.$$